# Допустимо ли ко времени в строковом формате применять функцию substr

Tags: php, чистый-код

Данный вопрос по принципам написания чистого кода и немножко по IT-этике. Можно ли для получения строковой даты из строки даты-времени использовать функцию `substr`?

```
$a = '2024-03-29 19:46:00';
// На самом деле значение берется из БД, столбца формата даты-времени
// Т.е. в полученной строке $a кроме даты-времени ничего быть не может
$b = substr($a, 0, 10);
```

Ведущий PHP-разработчик проекта возразил, что так писать ни в коем случае нельзя, т.к. данное написание не отражает замысла действия, а предложил следующий вариант:

```
$b = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($a));
// Аналогично, date, 'Y-m-d' и strtotime заменяют функции и константы для работы с временем из проекта
```

Насколько данное замечание является справедливым, и если да, то в каких рекомендациях регламентирован данный и другие подобные принципы кода?

Comment: Нужно быть готовым к тому, что формат хранения-получения даты из БД (здесь `$a`) может поменяться. И чтобы не исправлять код дважды, второй вариант был бы предпочтительнее. Но вы это и без меня, уверен, прекрасно понимаете...

Comment: *"регламентирован данный и другие подобные принципы кода"*  --- ну таких регламентов нет...но есть книжки, типа "чистый код" боба мартина.....

Comment: По текущему коду ведущий разработчик прав. Из вашего кода не ясно что он делает и зачем., а из его предложенного варианта сразу понятно, что нужно привести дату к какому-то формату, который при этом явно чётко и наглядно описывается....... в вашу же строчку можно впихнуть вообще всё что угодно. у вас работа со строкой, а у разраба явная работа с датой..... очевидно ваше решение нечитаемое абсолютно... Если кто-то другой будет читать, он не поймёт во-первых почему из даты берут подстроку, а во-вторых - вообще для каких целей это делается. почему именно 10 символов, а не 13

Comment: А вообще, если данные надо получить из БД, то можно сразу получить оттуда нужный формат, а не заниматься этим на сервере

Comment: данное замечание, как выше уже сказано, является справедливым на все 100. Тем не менее, вопрос следует закрыть так ответы будут основаны на мнениях. В общем вид строки возвращаемой из БД зависит от локали, потенциально можно получить совершенно другой формат даты, а не `^dddd-dd-dd`, так что строковые функции тут кроме непонятности еще и сломать код могут.

Comment: @teran, подождите, не закрывайте вопрос. Судя по комментариям, ответ вполне очевиден. И было бы неплохо какое-нибудь руководство по всем подобным случаям, чтобы им пользоваться, и не допускать таких ошибок

Comment: Само по себе допустимо. Но как правильно написано снизу, лучше это отрезание завернуть в функцию. Еще лучше работать с датой в специальном формате, Карбон или datetime. а strtotime - это такой же говнокод, вид сбоку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замечание крайне справедливо. Во-первых, как уже указали в комментариях, формат даты в БД может измениться: кто-то возьмёт и скажет, что лучше хранить даты как timestamps — целые числа секунд с начала эпохи Unix. И всё, ваш метод не сработает.
Но даже если не брать это в расчёт, сама строчка

```
$b = substr($a, 0, 10);
```

вообще не отражает смысла написанного кода. Что за подстрока, почему до десятого символа? Нужно писать обширный комментарий, заменять «магическое число» `10` на константу где-нибудь вверху класса, и т.д., и т.п.
А ещё есть такая штука, как type safety, безопасность типов. Современный PHP позволяет вполне неплохо работать с типами. Я не знаю, что вы собираетесь делать с этой датой потом, но есть вероятность, что вам будет полезнее взять дату для строки с помощью `DateTime::format()`, а сам объект продолжать хранить в переменной.

Ещё одна вещь, которую можно сделать, это использовать MySQL-функцию DATE, если вы используете эту базу данных:

```
SELECT `id, `something_else`, DATE(`my_date_time`) FROM `table` WHERE [...]
```

Comment: То есть получается обратное (`$b = $a . ' 23:59:59';`), то же может быть подвергнуто справедливому замечанию?

Comment: У вас здесь два довода, один из которых построен на домысле и очень так себе.

Comment: Павел, конечно. Это конкатенация строк, которая тоже непонятно, что делает и очень подвержена ошибкам в будущем.